# How to kick after a certain amount of infractions discord.js

Tags: discord.js, bots

I'm developing a discord.js moderation bot, and I want it to kick someone after a certain number of infractions. Is there a way I can get it to log those infractions (swearing), and then kick after a certain number of times? The bot already finds and deletes swearing, so I want to be able to implement this into that system. I want to know if there is a way to build the infraction logging system directly into the anti-swear. I'm not going to put the unmodified code in, because its anti-swear, and it needs something to base itself on, but I will place a censored version below

```
// require the discord.js module
const Discord = require('discord.js');

// create a new Discord client
const client = new Discord.Client();

// when the client is ready, run this code
// this event will only trigger one time after logging in
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('TOKEN');

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.includes('bad word')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('Please do not swear on this server.');
  }
  if (message.content.includes('bad word')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('Please do not swear on this server.');
  }
  if (message.content.includes('bad word')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('Please do not swear on this server.');
  }
  if (message.content.includes('bad word')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('Please do not swear on this server.');
  }
  if (message.content.includes('bad word')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('Please do not swear on this server.');
  }
  if (message.content.includes('bad word')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('Please do not swear on this server.');
  }
  if (message.content.includes('bad word')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('Please do not swear on this server.');
  }
  if (message.content.includes('bad word')) {
    message.delete();
    message.author.send('Please do not swear on this server.');
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a discord.js [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), which is:

> A Map with additional utility methods. This is used throughout discord.js rather than Arrays for anything that has an ID, for significantly improved performance and ease-of-use.

A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys. Any value may be used as either a key or a value. Here's a quick demo:

```js
// let's say we had two people: John and Sarah
const people = new Map();

// each of them were a different age
people.set('John', 25); // in this example, 'John' is the key, and 25 is the value
people.set('Sarah', 19); // in this example, 'Sarah' is the key, and 25 is the value

// each person has an individual age
// you can `get()` the key, and it will return the value
console.log(`Sarah is ${people.get('Sarah')} years old.`);
console.log(`John is ${people.get('John')} years old.`);
```

You can use this type of format to create a collection with each key being a different user ID, and each value being how many infractions they have. Every time someone swears, increment their infraction count by one and then check if it passes a given number.

Also, you can vastly simplify your current system by putting every bad word in an array, then iterating the *same function* through every element using [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
// const Discord = require('discord.js');

const infractions = new Discord.Collection();
const words = ["bad word", "bad word", "bad word", "..."];

// since it's the same function, you should only have to write it once
if (words.some((word) => message.content.includes(word))) {
  message.delete();
  message.author.send("Please do not swear on this server.");
  if (!infractions.has(message.author.id))
    // if they don't have any infractions
    infractions.set(message.author.id, 1);
  // create a new element for them with 1 infraction
  // otherwise, increment their existing infractions by 1
  else
    infractions.set(message.author.id, infractions.get(message.author.id) + 1);
  // check if it's above the specified number
  if (infractions.get(message.author.id) >= 5) {
    // kick the member, send log messages, etc.
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, except when they commit that amount of infractions, it takes no action. I set it to send a message for now, but it does nothing

Comment: Is there a way to log who was kicked and send it to a log server using the channel id?